# Tabs in action bar that contains extended action view reappear on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

In my Android app I use ActionBarSherlock to display two menu items. One is a search item with collapsed action view. Additionally, the action bar is set to `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` and contains three tabs. Those tabs are displayed in the action bar if there is enough space or below the action bar otherwise.

My problem appears on devices where there is enough space for the tabs in the bar:

[image]

If the search action view is extended, it is shown instead of the tabs, which is fine:

[image]

However, if the device is rotated, when the search action view is extended, the tabs reappear in the new orientation and overlap the search action view:

[image]

It's the same behavior on both *Galaxy Tab 10.1N* (running Android *4.0.4*), and on *Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus N* (running Android *3.2*).
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I appreciate any help!

Here's some code:

### default_menu.xml

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:id="@+id/SearchMenuItem"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
          android:title="@string/Search"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/search"
          android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/SettingsMenuItem"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
          android:title="@string/Settings"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

### search.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:hint="@string/Search"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white20"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_search_transparent"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

### Here's how I add tabs:

```java
protected void addTabBar() {
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTabListener(this), false);
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTabListener(this), false);
    ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("TAB3").setTabListener(this), false);
    ab.selectTab(ab.getTabAt(0));
}
```

Comment: Is someone able to reproduce this? Do you think it could be a bug in ActionBarSherlock or the 'original' ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in action bar Sherlock when force flow over occurs now it had been remoeved.See the version history 
here [Changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)...Please Update action bar sherlock or use action bar compat